# Can't mount mongodb directory volume with docker-compose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker-compose

In my main project directory I have another local directory that I store my mongodb data in which is `./pokemondb`. I know this directory is filled with my data because I have run `mongoimport --db stats --colletion pokemon --file stats.json` and can confirm the data is there in the `mongo` shell. I also have a docker-compose file that looks like this

```
pokemon-app:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - mongo

mongo:
  image: mongo:3.2.4
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
  volumes:
    - "./pokemondb:/data/db"
```

I run `docker-compose up` and no errors occur. But the problem is that the mongodb directory `/data/db` now doesn't contain the mounted volume I tried to pass. I can confirm that the data wasn't passed correctly by executing `docker exec -ti [mongo container id] bash` and checking the `/data/db` directory with the `mongo` shell, indeed nothing is there. What am I doing wrong and why is my mongodb data directory not mounting the volume correctly?

**EDIT**: I found an unexpected solution to my problem. One of my problems was that I had a fundamental misunderstanding of what docker volumes are. I previously thought that docker volumes were meant to copy data from your local machine into a docker container when it starts up. But in fact docker volumes are meant to save data on your local machine generated in the docker container. The solution the original problem I asked above was to create a dockerfile that copies the data into the image then import the data into the database when the container starts up. My final docker compose file looks like this.

```
app:
  build: .
  ports:
    - 3000:3000
  links:
    - mongodb

mongodb:
  image: mongo:3.2.4
  ports:
    - 27017:27017

stats:
  build: ./stats
  links:
    - mongodb
```

Comment: Did you check existed files in `./pokemondb` folder ? You just confirm data exsited by using mongo shell.

Comment: What os are you using ? Do you have something like SELinux running in your system?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan Yes the data is there locally, I've already checked with the `mongo` shell. @Fares I'm running OSX Yosemite

Comment: You should go to `/path/pokemondb` then run command: `ls -ls` to show files in that folder

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Docker Toolbox for OSX then only the home directory is available to the VM. If you're outside the your home directory, you need to either add another shared volume to the Virtualbox VM, or move the project under your home directory.

Comment: Are you saying that only files, not directories, outside the home directory can be mounted to a docker volume?

Comment: Sorry, I'm saying nothing outside of the home directory can be mounted, because the files aren't visible to the VM where docker is running.